# Проблема при поиске текста с запрещенной подстрокой между двух разделителей

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На сайте есть элементы `input` с атрибутом `name`, имеющим вид

```
CFV[1161170][5pGKucpYSQ][VALUE]
CFV[1161170][jk9Gh79SK2z][VALUE]
```

Также есть поля с атрибутом `name`

```
CFV[1161170][UNIQUE][VALUE]
```

Для поиска нужного элемента `input` по имени использую регулярное выражение `CFV\[1161170].*\[VALUE]`.

Как дописать выражение, чтобы находились только те элементы, у которых нет части `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать [tempered greedy quantifier:](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

```
\bCFV\[1161170\](?:(?!\[UNIQUE\]|\bCFV\[1161170\]).)*\[VALUE\]
```

[Демонстрация](https://regex101.com/r/vD5vG6/2)

"Жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор `(?:(?!\[UNIQUE\]|\bCFV\[1161170\]).)*` находит только тот текст, после которого нет `[UNIQUE]` и `CFV[1161170]`, и так до `[VALUE]`.

**Дополнение** (спасибо ReinRaus'у):

Можно воспользоваться "упрощённым" вариантом регулярного выражения ([см. в действии](https://regex101.com/r/vD5vG6/3))

```
\bCFV\[1161170\](?!\[UNIQUE\]).*?\[VALUE\]
```

Здесь используется (под)выражение `(?!\[UNIQUE\]).*?`, состоящее из `.*?` (находит любое количество (но как можно меньше) любых символов кроме перехода на новую строку) ЕСЛИ данная подстрока между `CFV[1161170]` и `[VALUE]` не равна `[UNIQUE]` (благодаря "блоку предварительного просмотра" `(?!\[UNIQUE\])`).

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.